# Android Intent setSelector

Tags: android, android-intent

Why when I use setSelector method it returns neither Camera activities nor Gallery Activities.I have the following code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent camera= new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

    Intent gallery = new Intent();  
    gallery.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
    gallery.setType("image/*");
    gallery.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    camera.setSelector(gallery);

    startActivity(camera);
}
```

According to Android's reference API "*If the selector is set, it will be used when trying to find entities that can handle the Intent, instead of the main contents of the Intent.*"

I thought that I will get a dialog that opens the gallery instead of camera. But, instead of these I got a dialog that returns arbitrary applications/activities, such as *Call Settings*, *Network Settings*, *SIM Toolkit*, etc.

When I remove the `camera.setSelector(gallery);` method everything works like a charm, but when I use `camera.setSelector(gallery);` method it returns neither Camera activities nor Gallery Activities.
Could somebody explain me why I got a dialog with these arbitrary activities instead of appropriate?
I don't want to remove the `camera.setSelector(gallery);` because I am trying to understand how it works!

Comment: What is your requirement ? you wan to open chooser dialog which shown option to pick image is it ?

Comment: If I remove the setSelector method every intent it works as it should. Why when I use setSelector method it returns neither Camera activities nor Gallery Activities. As I said, I want someone to explain me why I got arbitrary activities as options to respond to the camera intent.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code :

```
Intent camera= new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
```

With this :

```
Intent camera= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

Comment: I really appreciate your time spent to help me. But, maybe, what I want, it cannot explained using code. I am trying to understand the reason of appearing these arbitrary activities instead of appropriate, when I use the setSelector method.

Answer (score 0):

use this intent to open your gallery

```
Intent pickPhoto = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                       android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

then use startActivityForResult to get the selected photo from gallery. hope this helps

Comment: I am trying to understand the reason of appearing these arbitrary activities instead of appropriate.